# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined

Tags: angular, google-api

I'm stuck. I am trying to create a Google People API auth service in Angular.

I am getting an error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'people' of undefined
```

Can someone help me understand why?

```
declare var gapi: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;
  peopleItems: any[];

  constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.initClient();
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
  }

  initClient() {
    gapi.load('client', () => {

      gapi.client.init({
        apiKey: 'myapikey',
        clientId: '',
        discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest"],
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts'
      })
    });
  }

  async getPeople() {
    const mypeople = await gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
      resourceName: 'people/me',
      personFields: 'names,emailAddresses',
    })
    this.peopleItems = mypeople.people.people.list;
  }
}
```

Comment: Probaby because `mypeople.people` or `mypeople` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. I changed **this.peopleItems = mypeople.people.people.list** to **mypeople.result.connections**.

Comment: @GregHarner please mark the answer

Comment: I'm not sure what "mark the answer" means. I did go ahead and click the orange ^ icon. Is that marking an answer?

Comment: Ok, I see from the help that is not marking an answer. But, I do not see a button that allows me to mark an answer. Where is it hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took, **"mypeople.people.people.list"** from the Google quick start documents. However, the quick start was for javascript and I'm using Angular. @Bergi pointed me in the correct direction with his comment. I used the **chrome developer tools (F12)** console tab to find the line of code in the **sources** tab and added a breakpoint. I was then not only able to clearly see that **people** was undefined. It also showed me the correct path to get data from the object.

I hope there is some other beginner developer out there that can benefit from my answer.